# Erasing page on stm32 fails with FLASH_ERROR_WRP

Tags: stm32

I am trying to erase one page in flash on an STM32F103RB like so:

```
FLASH_Unlock();
FLASH_ClearFlag(FLASH_FLAG_BSY | FLASH_FLAG_EOP | FLASH_FLAG_PGERR | FLASH_FLAG_WRPRTERR | FLASH_FLAG_OPTERR);
FLASHStatus = FLASH_ErasePage(Page);
```

However, FLASH_ErasePage fails producing FLASH_ERROR_WRP

Manually enabling/disabling write protection in the stm32-linker tool doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Basically FLASH_ErasePage fails with WRP error without trying to do anything if there's previous WRP error in the status register.

What comes to your FLASH_ClearFlag call, at least FLASH_FLAG_BSY will cause assert_param(IS_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLASH_FLAG)); to fail (though I'm not really sure what happens in this case).

```
#define IS_FLASH_CLEAR_FLAG(FLAG) ((((FLAG) & (uint32_t)0xFFFFC0FD) == 0x00000000) && ((FLAG) != 0x00000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your page address ? Which address are you trying to access ?
For instance, this example is tested on STM32F100C8 in terms of not only erasing but also writing data correctly. 
http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/TR/eeprom-emulation-on-stm32/

Answer (score 0):

If using the HAL driver, your code might look like this (cut'n paste from an real project)

```
static HAL_StatusTypeDef Erase_Main_Program ()
{
    FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef ins;
    uint32_t sectorerror;

    ins.TypeErase = FLASH_TYPEERASE_SECTORS;
    ins.Banks = FLASH_BANK_1; /* Do not care, used for mass-erase */
#warning We currently erase from sector 2 (only keep 64KB of flash for boot))
    ins.Sector = FLASH_SECTOR_4;
    ins.NbSectors = 4;
    ins.VoltageRange = FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3; /* voltage-range defines how big blocks can be erased at the same time */
    return HAL_FLASHEx_Erase (&ins, &sectorerror);
}
```

The internal function in the HAL driver that actually does the work

```
void FLASH_Erase_Sector(uint32_t Sector, uint8_t VoltageRange)
{
  uint32_t tmp_psize = 0U;

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_FLASH_SECTOR(Sector));
  assert_param(IS_VOLTAGERANGE(VoltageRange));

  if(VoltageRange == FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_1)
  {
     tmp_psize = FLASH_PSIZE_BYTE;
  }
  else if(VoltageRange == FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_2)
  {
    tmp_psize = FLASH_PSIZE_HALF_WORD;
  }
  else if(VoltageRange == FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_3)
  {
    tmp_psize = FLASH_PSIZE_WORD;
  }
  else
  {
    tmp_psize = FLASH_PSIZE_DOUBLE_WORD;
  }

  /* If the previous operation is completed, proceed to erase the sector */
  CLEAR_BIT(FLASH->CR, FLASH_CR_PSIZE);
  FLASH->CR |= tmp_psize;
  CLEAR_BIT(FLASH->CR, FLASH_CR_SNB);
  FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_SER | (Sector << POSITION_VAL(FLASH_CR_SNB));
  FLASH->CR |= FLASH_CR_STRT;
}
```

Second thing to check. Is interrupts enabled, and is there any hardware access between the unlock call and the erase call?

I hope this helps